# cant get the value from a user after creating an input text in js

Tags: javascript

I need help to write a code that creates an input element and then get the user's input by click on button. 
Do I need 2 functions? one for creating the elements and other for the Game(?).
the main problem for me is to get the text value after creating input.

I created an element, but I dont know how I can "pull" out the value of the user's text.

```js
let btGame = document.querySelector("#game");
btGame.addEventListener('click', startGame)


function startGame() {
  createGame();

}


function createGame(textInputValue) {
  let gameBox = document.querySelector(".gameBox");
  let textInput = document.createElement("input");
  let btGuess = document.createElement("input");

  textInput.type = "text";
  textInput.id = "inputof";
  textInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'guess a number between 1-6');

  btGuess.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  btGuess.setAttribute('class', 'go');
  btGuess.value = "guess";


  gameBox.appendChild(textInput);
  gameBox.appendChild(btGuess);


}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gameBox {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dotted #ffc452;
}

.gameTitle {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: oblique;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gameTitle:hover {
  transition: 2s;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: gold;
}

#inputof {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gameBox">
    <h1 class="gameTitle">want to play a game?</h1>

    <input type="button" id="game" value="click here to start">
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listener to the created `btGuess` when `createGame` is called:

```js
let btGame = document.querySelector("#game");
btGame.addEventListener('click', startGame)


function startGame() {
  createGame();

}


function createGame(textInputValue) {
  let gameBox = document.querySelector(".gameBox");
  let textInput = document.createElement("input");
  let btGuess = document.createElement("input");

  textInput.type = "text";
  textInput.id = "inputof";
  textInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'guess a number between 1-6');

  btGuess.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  btGuess.setAttribute('class', 'go');
  btGuess.value = "guess";


  gameBox.appendChild(textInput);
  gameBox.appendChild(btGuess);

  btGuess.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('You inputted:', textInput.value);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gameBox {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dotted #ffc452;
}

.gameTitle {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: oblique;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gameTitle:hover {
  transition: 2s;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: gold;
}

#inputof {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gameBox">
    <h1 class="gameTitle">want to play a game?</h1>

    <input type="button" id="game" value="click here to start">
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

as CertainPerformance said, add an event listener to `btGuess` when createGame is called. I used a separate function to manage the game logic and inserted `guessValue` variable containing the value to guess when you click the `guess` button

```js
        let btGame = document.querySelector("#game");
        btGame.addEventListener('click' ,  startGame);
        var guessValue;

        function startGame()
        {
            createGame();
            guessValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            console.log(guessValue);
        }


        function createGame(textInputValue)
        {   
            let gameBox = document.querySelector(".gameBox");
            let textInput = document.createElement("input");
            let btGuess = document.createElement("input");

                textInput.type = "text";
                textInput.id = "inputof";
                textInput.setAttribute('placeholder' ,      'guess a number between 1-6');

                btGuess.setAttribute('type' , 'button');
                btGuess.setAttribute('class' , 'go');
                btGuess.value =  "guess";
                btGuess.addEventListener('click',() => play())
                
                gameBox.appendChild(textInput);
                gameBox.appendChild(btGuess);  
        }

function play(){
  let input = document.getElementById('inputof').value;
  console.log(input);
  if(input == guessValue){
    alert('You Won')
  }
  else {
    alert('Game over')
  }
}
```

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.gameBox
{
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dotted #ffc452;
}
.gameTitle
{
    font-family: cursive;
    font-style: oblique;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gameTitle:hover
{
    transition: 2s;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: gold;
}

#inputof
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="gameBox">
        <h1 class="gameTitle">want to play a game?</h1>
        
        <input type="button" id="game" value="click here to start">
    </div>
    
 </body>
```